# Copying dataLayer is returning {object Object}

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

When I execute copy(dataLayer) into the console, it is putting into my clipboard just an array of the text '{object Object}'

The issue is only happening after clicking on a button. On Page Load, it can copy it fine, but once I click on a button it is only coming back as the array of objects.

I've tried googling around, clearing my cache and cookies for the site, restarting my session/browser/laptop and still no progress

Essentially all I'm doing is using

```
copy(dataLayer)
```

I expect to receive a complete copy of the current dataLayer variable into my clipboard, but I end up getting:

'[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'

Comment: Did you try to print your `dataLayer` and your result value with for example `JSON.stringify(dataLayer)` ? Showing `[object Object]` is when your variable is some kind of complex object that your browser don't know how to show.

Comment: Tried that now, returning an error of converting a circular structure.     
  Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLButtonElement'
    |     property '__reactInternalInstance$m60vmkntts' -> object with constructor 'zr'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:11

Comment: Yeah ok... Do you know any way to get some information of your dataLayer object (`dataLayer.<insert property name here>` or `dataLayer.<insertMethodNameHere>()` ? then try to do the copy, and compare if the data are the same. To be sure it was a full copy, try to modify the dataLayer object or the copy, and check that the other is not updated.
Edit; What you show actually say nothing about if the copy was successful or not (just show that there is a difficulty to print the object properly)

Comment: can you share exact code where you are executing copy(dataLayer) ?

Comment: I cannot, it's a client's website and we don't have access to the code. All I'm doing is pulling out the dataLayer based on certain events on the page